# NotFoundHttpException - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i want to make edit-update function..
this is my code :

**Admin Controller**

```
  public function edit_ist($id_prog)
{
    $program_studi = ProgramStudi::find($id_prog);
    return view('edit_ist_program_studi',compact('program_studi'));
}
public function update_ist($id_prog)
{
    $istUpdate = Request::all();
    $program_studi = ProgramStudi::find($id_prog);
    $program_studi->update($istUpdate);
     return redirect('administrator');
}
```

Form open in **view edit_ist_program_studi**

```
 {{ Form::model($program_studi,['method'=>'PATCH','route'=>['update_prodi',$program_studi->id_prog]])}}
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::patch('admin_page/edit_prodi/{id_prog}',
['as' => 'update_prodi', 'uses' => 'AdminController@update_ist']);
```

But i found error NotFoundHttpException, can you help me to fix this ? thank you

Comment: your problem solved?

Comment: already solved @Md.SahadatHossain :D thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `GET` route to the edit page.

Add something like this:

```
Route::get('admin_page/edit_prodi/{id_prog}', ['as' => 'edit_prodi', 'uses' => 'AdminController@edit_ist']);
```

Comment: Thank you @Giovanni, actually i have already add the GET route :)